# Add Macro keys to keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Keyboard: Redragon Yama k550

Ubuntu: 20.04.3

Kernel: 5.15.13

Motherboard: MSI Pro Z690-A WIFI (MS-7D25)

Processor: I9 12900k

Natively the keyboard recognizes it to me quite well. The only drawback I have is that the macro keys (G1-G12) are recognized as F1-F12.

Is there a way that this is not the case and you can identify them as separate keys from the F?

I ask this too, because beyond the macro, I am using the Autokey application and I would like to have the macro keys as shortcuts. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Not the optimal solution to the question maybe, but it solves my need to make macros work as shortcuts.

What I did was install the Autokey application

Then, in the hotkey configuration I put a combination such as "shift + F1" and that does the function I need.

Then record a macro on the macro keys with "shift + F1", let's say in the macro G12

So when I press the macro G12, it applies what I have saved in the shortcut "shift + F1"

In this way, I can even have a python script executable with a macro key.